# Making 3D plot in R

Tags: r, plot, 3d

I have two vectors x and y of same length;

```
x <- c(12,14,14,15,16,18)
y <- c(25,36,32,30,36,42)
```

and function f

```
f <- function(a,b) {
sum((y - a - b*x)^2)
}
```

If a and b are two vectors such that:

```
a <- seq(from=-5,to=5, by=.1)
b <- seq(from=-2.5, to=7.5, by=.1)
```

I need to evaluate `f` for each and every possible pair of `a` and `b` so that I could make 3D plot for `a, b, and z=f(a,b)`.

I found `outer` function but this is not working. Can you please suggest me alternative so that I could achieved desired results?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In two separated parts, you can use the [plot3D](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plot3D/vignettes/plot3D.pdf) package:

```
library(plot3D)
```

(1) compute z = f(a, b) for each a, b

```
### Compute z = f(a, b)
a <- seq(from=-5,to=5, by=.1)
b <- seq(from=-2.5, to=7.5, by=.1)

X <- c(12,14,14,15,16,18)
Y <- c(25,36,32,30,36,42)

f <- function(a,b) {
  sum((Y - a - b*X)^2)
}

m <- expand.grid(a, b)
z <- mapply(f, m$Var1, m$Var2)
```

(2) Declare a mesh and plot the result upon it:

```
### Plot3D
M <- mesh(a, b)
x.plot <- M$x
y.plot <- M$y

z.plot <- matrix(z, nrow=nrow(x.plot))

persp3D(x.plot, y.plot, z.plot)
```

And this generates:

[image: persp3D plot]

The results have to be double-check though

Answer (score 1):

```
xy = expand.grid(a, b)
#     z = f(xy[,1], xy[,2])
mapply(f, xy$Var1, xy$Var2) # see comment below
```

The first makes the Cartesian product of `a` and `b`:

```
a = 1:3
b = 4:5
expand.grid(a, b)
# prints (I'm not sure about the row order)
# 1 4
# 1 5
# 2 4
# 2 5
# 3 4
# 3 5
```

Comment: This does not work as it is. You need to apply the function to `xy`, i.e. `mapply(f, xy$Var1, xy$Var2)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very straightforward solution using `curve3d` from the `emdbook` package,

```
curve3d(f(x,y), from=c(-5,-2.5), to=c(5,7.5), sys3d="persp", theta=90, phi=45)
```

gives

[image: curve3dpersp]